# How can I get the Data from costmap_2d in a file?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have implemented costmap_2d in my robot and now I want to get the information about obstacles, inflation and footprint inside a file and local planner. can you please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391266/how-can-i-get-the-data-from-costmap_2d-in-a-file?/) by [brokenglass](https://answers.ros.org/users/89988/brokenglass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-11-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @brokenglass

When you save the map to disk from the map server by:
`rosrun map_server map_saver -f <map_name>` two files will be generated.

Reference:  http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData

A .pgm file that is a visual picture of the map and .yaml file that will contain information you are looking for. However you need to know how to interpret this information:
Reference: http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

> The image describes the occupancy
> state of each cell of the world in the
> color of the corresponding pixel. In
> the standard configuration, whiter
> pixels are free, blacker pixels are
> occupied, and pixels in between are
> unknown. Color images are accepted,
> but the color values are averaged to a
> gray value.

You can take a look how [map_saver.cpp](https://github.com/strawlab/navigation/blob/master/map_server/src/map_saver.cpp) does it. Some people use OpenCV to read image and interpret the occupancy map.

If you want to do something more advanced, take a look at this package: Grid Map by Anybotics
https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map

And the information on local planner and global planner parameters are stored as .yaml files.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brokenglass](https://answers.ros.org/users/89988/brokenglass/) on 2021-11-22**:
Thank you but I want to introduce obstacles in my local planner. the map related work is done.
I am using NMPC local planner.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-22**:
NMPC is a plug-in to the base_local_planner. The principles are the same as stated in my answer. You don’t introduce obstacles to the local planner. The local planner reads the costmap including obstacles to determine potential trajectories.